# Trouble serving Auth0 dependencies on client with SystemJS

Tags: express, systemjs, auth0

I have an Angular2 and Express based web app. I am trying to implement a secured API endpoint, and am cheating and using Auth0. I am following the [guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login), however, it doesn't seem to be getting on with my setup. My app is currently crashing with:

> GET /angular2-jwt 404 30.433 ms - 14

Despite me having this `system.config.js`:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      //all the other angular packages
      'angular2-jwt':               'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
         main: 'Rx.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-jwt': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Why isn't my system.config.js working, or have I missunderstood how to use systemJS?

My **index.html** contains:

```
<script src="./config/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

if I add a console.log message directly above the `System.config({` line of my system.config, it isn't triggered. Does this mean my system.config isn't being read?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in system.config.js:

```
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api'
},no extension
packages: {
```

When I remove `no extension`, it requests as expected

```
GET /node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js
```

> if I add a console.log message directly above the System.config({ line of my system.config, it isn't triggered. Does this mean my system.config isn't being read?

Most likely, yes. You can check it by looking at the network activity tab in developer tools in your browser - there should be a request that fetches systemjs.config.js.

You can find an example with working import at https://github.com/fictitious/test-systemjs-angular (it does not do any authentication however).

Comment: I'm afraid that was a typo in the question (only partly removed a comment) and isn't the cause of the issue I'm facing. My fault - sorry.

Comment: That system.config.js is working - see https://github.com/fictitious/test-systemjs-angular . The issue is not in systemjs config.